# Email sent through my custom email address are ending up in spam

Tags: email, smtp, email-spam

I'm sending emails via this custom email address sales@decorbunny.a2hosted.com that I have but all the emails are ending up in spam. i have done all of the following authentications

- DKIM (Domain Key Identified Mail)
- SPF (Sender Policy Framework)
- DMARC – requires you to already be using DKIM and SPF

I also tested the emails score here at https://www.mail-tester.com/ and its 10/10. But still the emails end up in spam. Can anybody please tell what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're sending bulk emails make sure the list your using isn't bad and that your email address isn't marked as a spam address by services.
2. If your emails contain links to fishy/sketchy websites then it can be marked as spam.
3. Your using too many images or too much images with too little text.
4. You're sending too many attachments.
5. Your recipient marked you as spam.
6. Your outgoing email information is incorrect/bad

If you're using a hosting service then contact your provider and see if something is up or if they can provide any insight! Email's are next to printer's in how fun it is to troubleshoot. Goodluck! If it's just one email your sending to that is marking you as spam then check it's settings if you can, or ask that email address owner to whitelist you, that is if your not sending bulk. Don't go asking 100+ people to whitelist your address lol